# Correct way of doing navigation

Tags: seo, submenu

I am creating a wordpress website with multi-level of navigation.

When i say multi-level the parent link also has `<a href="#">`. I have this link for nothing. And this is creating issues when I check for Link quality in chrome extention "SEO Site Tools" It gave me I have over 200 links in my homepage and this is bad seo.

Is there anyway I can replace parent item link `<a href="#">` to `<span>`? If I do will search engine make my website as scam? This is the structure I am trying to implement.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Products</span>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="product-1">Product 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="product-2">Product 2</a></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

Comment: @unor Thank you so much unor. I was having problem formatting my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote seo site tools. The 200 links per page is really more of a rule of thumb... Im sure you will be fine. if you send the domain along ill take a look but I dont understand why you are listing all your products in the menu. the other thing you could do is for the deepest pages write the nav code out with javascript and then google wouldnt see all the links to every page on every other page. If you choose to go that way make sure google will still have a way to navigate to those pages (this is usually done with category listing pages)

Comment: Thank you Carter. I am glad i found you have a direct contact with you.

Comment: I can use javascript to build deepest pages on the navigation. But since i am modifying navigation with javascript will google mark my website as scam? Because I heard that google can read jaavascripts.